Why fetching secret first time via "SecretCache" is SUPER SLOW compared to via SecretsManagerClient
When I configure a SecretCache with a SecretsManagerClient it takes my app (running as a docker container on my local mac) 10-12 seconds to retrieve the secret from AWS Secrets Manager.
When instead, I call Secrets Manager directly using that same client (just to emphasize that regions, etc. are same in both calls) in my app it takes 5 seconds. Why is that? Under the hood, the first call should be the same as the second one
Note: SecretCache is from aws-java-sdk-1.x  and SecretsManagerClient for aws-java-sdk-2.x
I've repeated this experiment multiple times.
